# Springboot App consumes too much memory on docker

Tags: spring-boot, docker, tomcat, deployment, memory-leaks

Trying to deploy a **containerized springboot app** using **docker**.
here's my **Dockerfile**:

```
ROM openjdk:8
ADD app-1.0.jar app.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-Xmx64m", "-Xss256k", "-jar", "ecalio-landing.jar"]
```

And **runned** a **container** like this:

```
sudo docker run -d -m256m --restart=always server.tomcat.max-threads=5 --name=ecalio-landing
```

Once **deployed**, i used **apache benchmark** to **test** the **backend** and how much **requests** it can **reach** using this command:

```
ab -n 20000 -c 10 http://www.ecalio.com/
```

Basically, trying to know if the backend can reach 20000 requests 10 at a time, because i've **limited** the **container memory consumption** to **256mb**.

The **container starts** with **220mb** and **reaches** a **level arround 245mb** and **doesn't go further** **even if i rerun the same** **ab command**

**However**, when i try to **reach the backend using a browser**, **0.1mb is consumed each time i refresh the browser** and obviously the **container crushes once it reaches 256mb** of **memory consumption.**

**How come does such a thing happends** **?**

**I don't want my container to consume much memory**, it's basically a simple app which makes use of **jpa** with **1 entity** **model** only, and **perform only 1 retrieve** request called each time **/ url** is called using a simple **controller** (**@Controller**) and **returns** a **single html page** rendered with **thymeleaf**

I've used Java VisualVM With my app (launched locally on my machine without a docker container) and i can see clearly that my app doesn't have any leak of memory, the heap memory doesn't go further more than 68mb and used heap is always being cleared by the GC ...

[image: Profiling memory]

Comment: If each request adds 0.1MB to memory usage and it doesn’t decrease when the garbage collector runs, it sounds like you have a memory leak. A heap dump should help to find it.

Comment: Yes it doesn't decrease at all, even after a long period of time, it only increases, i've even tried to change GC algorithm to SerialGC, it didn't work, i don't use Spring Security in my app, does it have something to do with creating and not invalidating sessions ?

Comment: It's really hard to say without some more information. A heap dump should help to identify the cause.

Comment: I've just used Java VisualVM With my app (launched locally on my machine without a docker container) and i can see clearly that my app doesn't have any leak of memory, the heap memory doesn't go further more than 68mb and used heap is always being cleared by the GC ... i'll upload a picture to show you the result

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After so much struggles i've found the solution to that, and it's too ridiculous...

When those 2 options aren't passed to the JVM, it supposes that the container shares the same amount of resources as the host machine even if the -m parameeter is passed to the container's creation command...

```
-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions
-XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap
```

It means if i create a container using the -m300m to specify that my container shoudn't allocate more than 300mb, the jvm will still think that the container has right to 2gb of memory (where 2gb is my machine's physical memory)

Using these options, i was able to get my app working on 256mb container... How amazing when i know that one time, my container consummed up to 800mb...

sources:

[Official openjdk's docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/openjdk)

[Interresting article](https://medium.com/adorsys/jvm-memory-settings-in-a-container-environment-64b0840e1d9e)

My new Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8
ADD app.jar app.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-server", "-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions", "-XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap", "-jar", "app.jar"]
```

the `-server` is useful to let the JVM knows that the app is to be excuted in a server environnement, which will leads to some changement including GC dedicated algorithm for server environnements and some other behaviors which may be found in the offical documentation.

Note that no Xmx or Xss or whatever additional options are needed for memory limitation, as the JVM will fix everything by itself (more details in the article below)

Another thing to know is that this configuration is done automatically in the OpenJDK 11.